# What is the maximum size/number of lines of cassandra cqlsh_history and cli.history?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I am using cassandra version 2.1.16. I have verfied that the cli.history files contains max 501 lines. However I dont see there is a limit for cqlsh_history file. Any idea on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cqlsh` uses the `readline` Python module](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1.19/bin/cqlsh#L2157), and does not set a history length. By default, `readline` [does not limit the history file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/readline.c#L137).

This assumes you're using CPython 2.7. If you have a different interpreter, you can examine the default using

```
python -c "import readline; print readline.get_history_length()"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I can see the value of above api call is -1 which shows that the history is of infinite length .

Comment: surprisingly on my window where the python version is 2.7.3 the history length is 100  however on linux server where python version is 2.7.5 the history length is -1 .. As per my understanding the default value is -1 , However not sure how come the value is 100 in my local window machine.